# What is the importance of Geographical Settings in Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google, google-search-console, geotargeting

In my website, I have set geographical settings in Google Webmaster Tools as India. I am targeting traffic from India, but my site has content for almost all Asian countries. So what can I do? Do I need to change geographical setting from India to Unlisted? According to setting which is India is it mean Google do not show my site if someone searches from Pakistan? Or Do Google list my site but at the bottom of page for the keywords which belongs to Pakistan?

Answer (score 1):

[This post on the help section of Google Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en) should give you a reasonable answer.

But basically, if you are targeting people from different places, then keep it as unlisted, that way, if your site has relevant information to a search query in the area or for the subject, it will appear on the results.

Comment: I have increase in traffic when I set geographical setting to India.Now only visitors comes from India.I don't have any traffic from Pakistan.But before I set target to India,all traffic came from Pakistan.Now nothing.What to do ?